# In general, why use propietary (or non-standard/self-made) file types?

Tags: file, text, file-type, file-type-associations

Hopefully this isn't too broad of a question for here, but I am an amateur programmer who doesn't have much experience with super complex programming as of yet (I've mostly used C for basic microcontroller and interface stuff so far).

I've noticed that a lot of applications have odd filetypes to store text data that seem to be different for the sake of it. For example, Valve video games store user settings in 'config' files that can be easily edited by any text editor. Is there a specific reason for this?

**In other words, assuming the data doesn't need to be encrypted or secure in some way, why not store plain old text data in a plain old text file? What are common purposes of storing plain data in odd file types?**

Comment: The simplest benefit is that communicates to the file reader and user what format the data is in. For human-readable data, that allows file readers to use syntax highlighting to make the data easier to read. A `.json` will be highlighted nicely in Notepad++ for example.

Comment: If the file can be edited by any text editor, then how is it not a plain old text file?

Comment: @JBNizet So, in the example I gave with the config files, the filetype is 'config'. However, they can be opened in any text editor since the file is just plain text. What I mean to ask is what is the purpose of having a non-standard filetype for what is essentially a txt file.

Comment: config is the file *extension*. There is no such thing as standard extensions for files containing text. Using .txt would give the feeling that the file is a random document. Using .config makes it clear that it's a config file, with a specified structure and content. It also allows associating these files to programs able to make sense of the content in those files. Take MS office .docx files for example. They're in fact zip files. But it would be quite annoyoing if they chose .zip as the extension: you wouldn't be able to differentiate random zip archives from MS office documents.

Comment: First of all, my mistake for misremembering the extension, it's .CFG not .config. Anyways, are file type and file extension different things? I called it a file type because that's how Windows Explorer labels it. (Or atleast 'Type')

Comment: The terminology doesn't matter much. The extension, or the type, doesn't reflect if the file contains text or binary. Otherwise the only 2 extensions we would have would be .txt and .bin. It reflects what the file contains. Is it an office document (.docx, binary)? A spreadsheet (.xlsx, binary)? A JSON document (.json, text)? An windown initialization file (.ini, text), etc. etc.